# shaping a tricky shape on a div

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve this shape in css, tried in several different ways, checked online for examples but looks like this shape is kind of tricky to accomplish.
Anyone that could have an idea of how to do this? Not sure if it's even possible with css only technique.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: what have you tried? I'm afraid all similar tricks on the net are just hacks using css borders. It's a nice effect, but you won't be able to place a text inside. I suggest using background image, it is simple, cross-compatible and I'm afraid the only solution

Comment: once try my solution...

Comment: It's possible and it's really simple. I'll make a demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and it's very simple.

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/FHuKd)

**Result**:

**[image: result]**:

I'm using just one element and a pseudo for the bottom left corner so the **HTML** is simply:

```
<div class='shape'></div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.shape {
  overflow: hidden; /* to hide the top right corner 
                       of the parallelogram formed by the pseudo */
  position: relative;
  width: 20em; height: 10em; /* any values really */
}
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 150%; height: 150%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(-3deg) skewX(-10deg);
  background: black;
  content: '';
}
```

You can get **a lot** of shapes using CSS transforms. And they are real shapes, you can have any kind of background behind.

Comment: hi, can we reshape a div on user event , (I am already performing resizing of the div when user clicks on border),and also can I save the cordinates of the new shape and render it on a different screen, if a post is required I can create with working stackblitz link

Answer (score 1):

I think it is perfect solution to your question...

```
#trapezoid {
 height: 0;
 width: 120px;
 border-bottom: 80px solid #05ed08;
 border-left: 45px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 padding: 10 8px 5 5;
}
```

Comment: Hey man!! that is so close!!! The tricky part if you see is the bottom part which is also a diagonal, on this css you sent me it's straight, the right border shoudl be straight but I fixed that changing the border right to 0px or even deleting that. The tricky part is that bottom, but what you sent me is SO close. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `:before`, `:after` pseudo and `transform` property. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nxQGH/1/).

```
#box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #212121;
    position: relative;
}

#box:after, #box:before {
    display: block;
    content: "\0020";
    color: transparent;
    width: 411px;
    height: 45px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
#box:before {
    bottom: 80px;
    left: -200px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(92deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(92deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(92deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(92deg);
    transform: rotate(92deg);
}
```

*You may have to change some values to get the shape you want.*

Comment: This can work yes, but only if you have a solid color on the background. the background:white; or whatever other color you put has to be the same than the color on background.
If you're over an image for example (over a banner let's suppose) you can't use this technique, correct?

Comment: Correct, in that case I'd recommend using an image instead of CSS.